# When is contra-variance useful? Why use covariance vs. inheritance?

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, contravariance

Can someone give example when is contra-variance useful?
and why use covariance vs. inheritance?

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html

Comment: Contra-variance or co-variance are neither usefull or useless. Some kinds are co-variant, in-variant or contra-variant just by their nature. Its more like acidity, basicity or neutrality... acids are just acidic and bases are just basic. Also variance is a higher lavel concept built on top of inheritance. For kinds, variance is similar to what inheritance is for types.

Comment: A great example of  when contravariance is useful are **functions**. Functions are contravariant on their inputs. So, for example, assume you need a function that goes from **Pets** to **Colors** but you already have a function that goes from all **Animals** to **Colors**, thanks to contravariance you can use that function and you know it will work, because if the function is able to handle all animals, why it won't be able to handle pets if those are a subtype of the former. - BTW, I do not understand what you mean by using inheritance instead of covaraince?

Comment: Old but still good: http://julien.richard-foy.fr/blog/2013/02/21/be-friend-with-covariance-and-contravariance/

Comment: The Comparable interface in Java is a great example of contravariance. Methods that use Comparable objects often have type parameters like `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`. This allows you to compare 2 objects even if they just inherit the compare methods from their superclasses and haven't implemented them themselves

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone give example when is contra-variance useful?

Contra-variance is not useful. It is just a property that some type constructors have.

Some integers are odd, some integers are even. That's just a property that those integers have.

Similarly, some type constructors are covariant in a type parameter or contra-variant. (Or invariant.)

> and why use covariance […]?

It's also not something you use. It's just something that *is*.

> and why use covariance vs. inheritance?

This question doesn't really make sense. Not only for the reason mentioned above (that covariance is simply something that *is* rather than something you use), but also because of the relationship between the two: variance is something that is a *consequence* of the interaction between subtype polymorphism and parametric polymorphism.